# How to define where Banshee stores the music in Android devices?

Tags: 13.04, android, music, banshee

I recently bought a Samsung S4 Mini instead of a new iPhone, hoping that I'd be able to sync my music to the external SD card using Ubuntu 13.04. I've managed to get banshee to copy a single track at a time, but it copies it to the music folder in the internal storage. Could anyone please help me change the target folder, so that it saves onto the SD card instead?

When I right click the device in Banshee, and click properties, the capacity shown includes that of the external card.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.is_audio_player` file inside the root directory of the Mass Storage Device — my phone.

Then you need to add a few lines into the file:

```
audio_folders=My Music/
folder_depth=2
output_formats=audio/mpeg,audio/mp3,audio/x-aac
```

From [here](http://act1v8.wordpress.com/2007/10/07/make-banshee-recognize-your-mass-storage-device-as-a-dap/).

I changed mpeg to flac